# How can I reformat 1 1/2 into pretty fraction HTML using regex and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a string like `5 1/36` that I want to rewrite as `5 <sup>1</sup>&frasl;<sub>36</sub>`.  Before the fraction, there can either be nothing or a space, and after the fraction there can either be a space or nothing. A string could contain multiple fractions.  The fractions may be positive or negative.

example:

```
myString = '(1 3/4)÷(-2/3)-(-6)-(6)-(1)+(-4)';
```

Comment: might consider unicode for the output, several fractions are very pretty around &#8530;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
var regex = /(\d+)\/(\d+)/g;
var myString = "(1 3/4)÷(-2/3)-(-6)-(6)-(1)+(-4)";
var myResult = myString.replace(regex, "<sup>$1</sup>&frasl;<sub>$2</sub>");
// "(1 <sup>3</sup>&frasl;<sub>4</sub>)÷(-<sup>2</sup>&frasl;<sub>3</sub>)-(-6)-(6)-(1)+(-4)"
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple string replacement for numbers about a `/` should do the trick

```
str = str.replace(/\b(\d+)\/(\d+)/g, '<sup>$1</sup>&frasl;<sub>$2</sub>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example:

```js
myString = '(1 3/4)÷(-2/3)-(-6)-(6)-(1)+(-4)';

document.write(myString.replace(/(\d+)(\/)(\d+)/g,
  '<sup>$1</sup>&frasl;<sub>$3</sub>'))
```